# Functions work when in a Sage worksheet directly but not when in a library

Tags: sage

I'm taking a class, Intro to Algebraic Cryptology.  We're using Sage for everything and CoCalc.  This class is the first I've heard of either.  The instructor has provided many convenience functions for our use.  I do not like repeatedly copying them into new Sage worksheets in CoCalc.  So, I put them in a library.

It took some time but I finally learned that to use them I have to do this in Sage:

```
load_attach_path('/path/to/the/directory')
%attach elliptic_curve_common.sage
```

Now, there is a function which she wrote for us to use called `HPSonEC`.  This function is about using the Hellman-Pohlig-Silver exploit for cracking encryption on elliptic curves.  What's infuriating is that the function will not work when used as I have above and I get this error:

```
Error in lines 5-5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cocalc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/smc_sagews/sage_server.py", line 1230, in execute
    exec(
  File "", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 298, in HPSonEC
  File "<string>", line 263, in listptorder
  File "<string>", line 151, in ECTimes
  File "sage/rings/rational.pyx", line 2401, in sage.rings.rational.Rational.__mul__ (build/cythonized/sage/rings/rational.c:20911)
    return coercion_model.bin_op(left, right, operator.mul)
  File "sage/structure/coerce.pyx", line 1248, in sage.structure.coerce.CoercionModel.bin_op (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce.c:11304)
    raise bin_op_exception(op, x, y)
TypeError: unsupported operand parent(s) for *: 'Rational Field' and 'Abelian group of points on Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 389787687398479 over Finite Field of size 324638246338947256483756487461'
```

However, if I take that function, and the others on which it depends, and copy them into my Sage worksheet, they work just fine.  Literally, no differences in the code at all.  What may be the issue?

Comment: Ideally, provide a minimal reproducible example: as few lines as possible that we can put in a `.sage` file to try and reproduce the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading code from a worksheet or a `.sage` file,
the Sage preparser is applied.

When reading code from a `.py` file, it is not.

See many questions where this came up:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsage%5D+preparser
- https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/page:1/query:preparser/

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  When I said library I may have given the wrong impression.  In CoCalc, I'm not using any `*.py` files.  The worksheet is `*.sagews` and the library file I made is just `*.sage`.  Should I be using `*.py`?

Comment: Using `.sage` files will be the closest to working in the worksheet. Using `.py` files is a bit trickier as import statements are required and there is no preparsing.

Comment: Can you say a word on how you solved the problem?